# Submit page but dont refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a footer generator.
Which looks like this: 
[image]

This "preview" button has 2 functions function 1 is posting the values that the user entered in the black box like this :

[image]

and the second function is to show me a button(which is hidden by default with css) called "button-form-control-generate" with jquery like this:

```
$("button.form-control").click(function(event){
    $("button.form-control-generate").show();
});
```

Now here comes my problem:

If i click on preview it refreshes the page.. so if i click on preview it shows the hidden button for like 1 second then it refreshes the page and the button goes back to hidden. So i tried removing the `type="submit"` but if i do that it wont post the entered data like it did in image 2 it will show the hidden button though, but because the submit type is gone it wont post the entered data on the black box.

Here is my code:

```
<form class ="form" method="post">

            <h3>Select your trademark</h3>

                <select class="form-control" name="trademark" action="">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>©</option>
                    <option>™</option>
                    <option>®</option>
                </select>

            <h3>Your company name</h3>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Your company name" />

                <br/>
                <br/>

            <button class="form-control" type= "submit" name="submit">
                Preview
            </button>
            <br/>
            <button class="form-control-generate"name= "submit">
                Generate
            </button>
        </form>




<!-- script for the preview image -->

        <div id = "output">
        <?php

        function footerPreview ()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

            $trademark = $_POST["trademark"];

            $company = $_POST["companyName"];

            $date = date("Y");

            echo "<div id='footer_date'>$trademark $date $company </div>";
        }

        footerPreview();

        ?>
```

The jquery:

```
$("button.form-control").click(function(event){
    $("button.form-control-generate").show();
});
```

Already tried prevent default but if i do this the users entered data doesnt show in the preview box. Looks like preventdefault stops this bit from working:

```
<!-- script for the preview image -->

        <div id = "output">
        <?php

        function footerPreview ()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

            $trademark = $_POST["trademark"];

            $company = $_POST["companyName"];

            $date = date("Y");

            echo "<div id='footer_date'>$trademark $date $company </div>";
        }

        footerPreview();

        ?>
```

I heard this is possible with ajax, but i have no idea how in this case i already tried to look on the internet..

Comment: In a general sense, you'd use the jQuery `$.ajax()` function to submit the form from code, without refreshing the page.  The response received in code would then be used however you need to use it.  If the response is JSON data, you'd use that data to update elements on the page.  If the response is HTML, you'd probably replace existing page elements with the new ones.

Comment: Try ajax. It submits your form without refreshing page. Also you do not have action for your form.

Comment: Yes ajax is the soultion... here a really nice introduction: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp ... try to understand it and try to find a solution, if you can't then come back and post your code with the ajax part, so we'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
return false;
```

to your jQuery-function at the end. With this you can avoid the submit.

Then you need to add an ajax-function, which sends the data from your form to the php-script you already use.

This is just an example:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "YOUR-PHP-SCRIPT"
        }).done(function (content) {
            // ADD HERE YOUR LOGIC FOR THE RESPONSE
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('failed: ' + textStatus);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have a `type="submit"` inside a form, it will submit the form by default. Try to use `<input type="button"` instead. Then you can use ajax on the button action, that will run without refreshing the page.

Here's an example of how to use ajax:

```js
function sendAjax() {
  var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  $(".result").html(JSON.stringify(data))
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="sendAjax()" value="callAjax" />
  <div class="result"></div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have to do $.ajax post request to the php. Something like this:

```
<script>
$('.form-control').click(function() {
    $.post(url, {data}, function(result) {
         footerPreview();
    }, 'json');
});
</script>
```

So `footerPreview` will be called when your php returns result.

Answer (score 1):

//add in javascript

```
function isPostBack()
{
   return document.referrer.indexOf(document.location.href) > -1;
}

if (isPostBack()){
   $("button.form-control-generate").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an index.php:

```
<form class ="form" method="post">

            <h3>Select your trademark</h3>

                <select class="form-control" name="trademark" id="tm">
                    <option val=""></option>
                    <option val="©">©</option>
                    <option val="™">™</option>
                    <option val="®">®</option>
                </select>

            <h3>Your company name</h3>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" id="cn" placeholder="Your company name" />

                <br/>
                <br/>

            <button class="form-control" type= "submit" name="submit">
                Preview
            </button>
            <br/>
            <button class="form-control-generate" name= "submit" id="generate">
                Generate
            </button>
</form>

<div class="output" id="output">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#generate').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var companyname = $('#cn').val();
        var trademark = $('#tm').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post'.
            data: {'company':companyname,'trademark':trademark},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                $('#output').append("<div id='footer_date'>"+data.trademark + " " + data.date + " " + data.company + " </div>");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error During AJAX');
            }
        });

    })
</script>
```

and the process.php:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$trademark = $_POST["trademark"];

$company = $_POST["company"];

$date = date("Y");

$array = array(
    'trademark' => $trademark,
    'company' => $company,
    'date' => $date
);

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Be sure that the index.php and the process.php will be under the same folder.. ex.public_html/index.php and public_html/process.php